# JavaScript setInterval issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, performance, dom-events

I'm try to create a stop Watch which will take the minutes from the input box and then I'm converting it into seconds. And I decremented the seconds one by one, I'm using a 'set Interval' method to do that. but it won't work. This is how my JavaScript file looks like:

```
window.onload = function(){
    //creating the inputminutes text Box
    var inputMin = document.createElement("input");
    inputMin.setAttribute('id','inputMin');
    inputMin.setAttribute('type','text');
    //creating the submit button
    var btn = document.createElement('input');
    btn.setAttribute('type','submit');
    btn.setAttribute('id','submit');
    btn.setAttribute('value','Start');

    document.getElementById('form').appendChild(inputMin);
    document.getElementById('form').appendChild(btn);


    document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function() {     
        function countDown(){
            var minutes = document.getElementById('inputMin').value;
            if(isNaN(minutes)) {
                alert("Please Enter a number...");
                return;
            }
            var seconds = parseFloat(minutes * 60);
            seconds--;
            return seconds;
        }
        var tick = setInterval(countDown(),2000);

        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = tick.toString();
    }   
}
```

And this is how my html looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin:auto;
            width:500px;
        }
        h2{
            font-size: 40px;
            font-family: Arial;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form"></form>
    <h2 id="time">0.00</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Can someone please give me an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe you should......explain exactly what's going wrong..... Other than "it wont work".

Comment: Stop changing posted code so much: SO should not be used as a "live debugger" and there are better ways to analyze a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not quite using `setInterval` correctly. `setInterval` returns a handle to the interval, so that you could clear it with `clearInterval`. It is not returning the seconds from the `countDown` function. I would move the `document.getElementById('time').innerHTML` into the bottom of the `countDown` function and set it directly on the seconds. Also `setInterval` takes a function as the first parameter, so don't include the `()` at the end, this is actually executing the function i.e. `setInterval(countDown,2000)` I also wouldn't declare the function inside the `onsubmit` handler, there is no need, and you may get scoping issues. Also the start of the `countDown` function always gets the value out if `inputMin` box, so always resets itself, to be honest you would be best to change it to a `setTimeout` and call itself recursively. Also you need to stop the form from posting, this will just straight away refresh the page (and appear to do nothing). I would potential not use a form, as you are not really wanting it to post (submit), just hook up a click handler to a button perhaps.

So something like the following should resolve things

```
window.onload = function () {
    //creating the inputminutes text Box
    var inputMin = document.createElement("input");
    inputMin.setAttribute('id', 'inputMin');
    inputMin.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    //creating the submit button
    var btn = document.createElement('input');
    btn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    btn.setAttribute('id', 'submit');
    btn.setAttribute('value', 'Start');

    document.getElementById('form').appendChild(inputMin);
    document.getElementById('form').appendChild(btn);


    document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function (e) {
        //Start the countDown with the value from the box, as seconds
        setTimeout(function(){countDown(document.getElementById('inputMin').value * 60)}, 2000);
        return false; //Need to also stop the post of the form

    }
}
function countDown(seconds) {    
    if (isNaN(seconds)) {
        alert("Please Enter a number...");        
    }
    else
    {
        seconds--;
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = seconds;
        if (seconds > 0) {
            setTimeout(function () { countDown(seconds); }, 2000);
        }
    }  

}
```

Comment: Just made an edit, realized there is a lot more logic issues with your code

Answer (score 0):

i figure out how to solve it.... using this java script solution....

```
<div id="time">ddd</div>
<script> 
 var seconds=0
 var minutes=1 
 time.innerHTML = "My new text!";
function display(){ 
 if (seconds<=0){ 
    seconds=59 
    minutes-=1 
 } 
 if (minutes<=-1){ 
    seconds=0 
    minutes+=1 
 } 
 else 
    seconds-=1 
    time.innerHTML = minutes+"."+seconds ;
    setTimeout("display()",1000) 
} 
display() 

</script>
```